# Stop Jenkins checking out Git URL in a Pipeline stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have setup a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline job, and it pulls the Jenkinsfile from Git. I have a stage that is running on a another node (selected by a label), but it is trying to checkout the Jenkinsfile from Git too.

How can I stop this behavior? This particular slave is on the other side of a firewall and I can only reach it by SSH.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the skipDefaultCheckout() in the options block. This will disable the checkout of the SCM on any node in any stage, so you will have to do a `checkout scm` step in the other stages manually.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
    stages{
        stage('first stage') {
            steps {
                checkout scm   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it is skipDefaultCheckout(). You show that in your pipeline example, but use the wrong term in your description. Probably should clean that up.

Comment: Oops. Fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: There is also a stage-level option `skipDefaultCheckout`. So alternatively one could leave it on at pipeline level and only skip at specific stages.

Comment: Thanks, this just saved me. Just out of curiosity, what's the main reason for the default behaviour of checking out the repo, given how easy and common is the git step to do it manually?

Comment: ..I mean,  most projects I worked on keep pipelines, sources etc in different repos , we always need an explicit scm step anyway, so I cant see how it's an useful default.